# Шаблонный связный список на Си

Tags: c, структуры-данных

Решил реализовать различные шаблонные структуры данных на чистом Си, и вот в связи с этим возникло несколько проблем...

1. Как было бы лучше организовать добавление данных в структуру? Брать сразу ссылку на элемент и работать с ней или брать ссылку, её размер и выделять под неё память, и после работать с ней?

   ```
   void push_back_list(list_t* list, void* data);
   void push_back_list(list_t* list, void* data, size_t size);
   ```
2. На данный момент я написал функцию, которая инициализирует список в куче:

   ```
   list_t* init_list()
   {
       list_t* list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
       list->head = NULL;
       list->tail = NULL;
       list->size = 0;
       return list;
   }
   ```

Но стоит ли также реализовать метод инициализации списка в стеке, к примеру, чтобы это выглядело вот так?

```
list_t* init_list_in_heap();
list_t init_list_in_stack();
```

Comment: Надо понять где и как вам это будет удобней использовать, от этого и отталкиваться. Лишние методы которые не будут задействованы плодить нет смысла.

Comment: Возьмем для примера, создание библиотеки контейнеров...

Comment: Тогда творческих подходов может быть много :) посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/ClnViewer/LinkedHashMap/blob/35955245f42277de68226093aec2d017639fc1fa/src/hashmap-link-hash.c#L488) возможно наведёт на мысли о реализациях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Добавление в список

Версия, принимающая размер `size_t size` имела бы смысл для ситуаций, если память выделяется внутри функции. Но что это даст? Сырая выделенная память в качестве элемента списка вряд ли будет полезной. Эти данные нужно как-то проинициализировать, а стало быть, вернуть наружу адрес свежевыделенной памяти. В данном случае параметр `void* data` здесь не поможет, нужен двойной указатель `void** data`, чтобы вернуть примерно так:

```
*data = malloc(size);
```

Если же двойного указателя не будет, придётся потом, после `push_back_list` вызвать другую функцию, возвращающую адрес свежесозданной памяти, или напрямую обратиться к какому-нибудь `list->tail`. Но сам факт добавления в список неинициализорованной памяти при том, что `size` уже будет её учитывать наравне с любым другим полноценным элементом заставляет задуматься, а надо ли оно такое.

Может быть и ещё вариант передать в функцию добавления указатель на функцию-конструктор (понятно, что в C никаких конструкторов нет, назвал по аналогии с более высокоуровневыми языками), которая будет выполнять необходимую инициализацию. Но здесь снова возникают вопросы, например, какая сигнатура должна быть у такой функции, чтобы удовлетворить всем возможным типам объектов, добавляемых в список.

В общем, версия с размером выглядит не очень подходящей.

Версия же без размера выглядит, как минимум, лаконичнее, а это уже плюс. К тому же в список будет добавляться элемент, который уже (должен бы быть) инициализован, хотя по-прежнему остаётся возможность добавить и просто сырую память, если вдруг "припрёт". Возвращать адрес нового элемента никуда не надо, т.к. элемент был создан снаружи функции добавления. Ещё один плюс. Т.о. версия без размера является более гибкой.

### Инициализация списка

Примерно та же ситуацию, что и с добавлением. Не надо делать различных версий, работающих с кучей/стеком. Более того, при возвращении объекта ещё и лишние копирования данных возможны. Просто используйте функцию вида:

```
void init_list(struct list_t* lst);
```

инициализирующую список по полученному адресу. А чему этот адрес принадлежит: куче, стеку или ещё какой неведомой зверушке - решает код, присутствующий выше. Например:

```
struct list_t lst; // стек
init_list(&lst);

...

struct list_t* plst = malloc(sizeof(struct list_t)); // куча
init_list(plst);
```